# Set UIScrollView.setContentOffset without scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` which shows a range of different plots. I want the UIScrollView to scroll from LEFT to RIGHT, so I want to set the `ContentOffset` of the `UIScrollView` to the "end" of the `ContentOffset`. I do it like this, which works:

```
var point = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.size.width, 0)
scrollView.setContentOffset(point, animated: true)
```

However, this means that it will scroll the entire offset to that specific point, which results in the user seeing all the plots flashing by. Of course I would just like the UIScrollView to start at that particular point without scrolling to it, but I can't figure out what to do. If I set `animated: false` the scrolling stops working altogether.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the same method with 'false' but make sure you set the contentSize of the scrollview before you make the above call for scrolling to take effect.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it earlier but had a lot of weird crashes, turns out it was something weird that I did which caused it to crash. Thanks again.